# Swift4.1 : How to remove delivered notification from notification list without open application

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Our app is one to one chatting application, We need to implement delete message functionality same as WhatsApp application, When ever I'm delete message from one device at that time automatically remove tray notification from second device which have already delivered notification from first device.

I've tried to find out remove notification from tray without opening our application.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `UserNotification` framework you can simply remove it by calling `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String]` -> [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649500-removedeliverednotifications)

If your question is about how to get the application to call this function -> you could solve this with via Silent Push Notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating `UNNotificationServiceExtension`
And then remove by `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers identifiers: [String]`